# Pandas: remove encoding from the string

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
  str_value
0 Mock%20the%20Week
1 law
2 euro%202016
```

There are many such special characters such as `%20%`, `%2520`, etc..How do I remove them all. I have tried the following but the dataframe is large and I am not sure how many such different characters are there.

```
dfSearch['str_value'] = dfSearch['str_value'].str.replace('%2520', ' ')

dfSearch['str_value'] = dfSearch['str_value'].str.replace('%20', ' ')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `urllib` library and apply it using [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method of a series.
Example -

```
In [23]: import urllib

In [24]: dfSearch["str_value"].map(lambda x:urllib.unquote(x).decode('utf8'))
Out[24]:
0    Mock the Week
1              law
2        euro 2016
```

Comment: Thank you. But it converted `euro%25202016` to `euro%202016`. Is this correct?

Comment: There is one more term after I applied your code, which is `nature%27s%20weirdest%20events`

Comment: @chintans Have you applied urlencoding twice? This `euro%25202016` is basically urlencoding of `euro%202016` (The `%` is url encoded to `%25`)

Comment: This is from the original csv file. But it appears that the encoding has been applied twice by the person who generated the data. Is there any work around?

Comment: This is what I did and it seems to be working. `dfSearch['str_value'] = dfSearch['str_value'].str.replace('%25', '%')` then your solution. But is this correct?

Comment: @chintans Maybe you can simply try repeating the unquote part twice to see what happens (If you get the desired results, then your csv has been twice encoded). Something like this - `urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(x).decode('utf8')).decode('utf8')` just to see if it works(if it does, you can clean up this code :p)

Comment: @chintans Try the above^ (replace %25 for % is a solution only for space, might not work for other chars)

Comment: The unquote part twice doesn't work. I will stick to replacing `%25` with `%` and then your solution. Thanks again:)

Comment: Heads up,  docs have changed - this worked for me:  dfSearch["str_value"].map(lambda x:urllib.parse.unquote(x, encoding='utf-8')) https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html